# optimization, reduction variables, and MATLAB parfor

Tags: matlab, optimization

I'm trying to write a simple generic parallel code for minimizing a function in MATLAB. The idea is very simple, essentially:

```
parfor k = 1:N
    (...find a good solution xcurrent with cost fcurrent ... )
    % keep best current value
    fmin = min(fmin,fxcurrent)
end
```

This works fine, because fmin is a reduction variable, and thus I can use this construction to update the current best value.

However, I couldn't find a nice elegant way of keeping (or storing) the best current solution ("xcurrent").

How do I keep track of the best solution found so far?

In other words, if the current value is strictly smaller than fmin, how can I save xcurrent (subject to the constraints that parallel loops impose in MATLAB)?

[Of course, the serial version is trivial, just prepend

```
if fxcurrent < fmin;
xbest = xcurrent;
end;
```

but this does not work on a parfor loop.]

A few approaches that come to mind:

- I could just store all solutions and costs (using sliced variables), but this is hugely memory inefficient (the number of iterations N is very large, and the solutions themselves are very big).
- Similarly, I could use a (set or matrix) reduction variable and do:

  ```
  solutionset = [solutionset,xcurrent]
  ```

but this is almost as bad in terms of memory requirement.

- I could also save xcurrent to disk every time the solution is improved.

I tried to look around for a simpler solution, but nothing was very useful.

The question seems to be well-defined (so it's not like in other problems, where the output could depend on iteration order), but I couldn't find an elegant way of doing this.

Apologies in advance if I'm missing something obvious, and thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: It depends on what you understand by "keeping track". Do you just want a display of some kind, just the current value - or do you require the whole development? Please clarify.

Comment: Thanks. I just want to save it, or store it for later use. I'll edit the original post to clarify.

Comment: At first I'd suggest to keep all the xcurrent and afterwards do the search for minimum. But you wrote something about memory - is N so large?

Comment: Yes, N is *really* large. This is a combinatorial optimization problem, and I cannot afford to store all the "xcurrent" that are being generated.

Comment: Just an idea- what if you write your own reduction function - basically just containing the if block and a save or output?

Comment: That's a great idea. I just looked at the documentation (again!), and found an example (under the heading "Using a Custom Reduction Function"), that is pretty close to what I want to do. If you write your comment as an answer, I'll vote it, and explain a bit more.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks so I copy the suggestion down here.

Just an idea- what if you write your own reduction function - basically just containing the if block and a save or output?

Comment: Thanks! It seems that this is the "recommended" way to go. In the documentation ([link](http://www.mathworks.de/help/toolbox/distcomp/brdqtjj-1.html)), I found an example (under the heading "Using a Custom Reduction Function"), that is pretty close to what I want to do. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will presumably need to maintain multiple `xcurrent` structures in memory anyway, since there will have to be a separate copy for each worker executing the loop-body. I would try splitting your loop into an outer parallel part and an inner serial part -- this will allow you to adjust the number of copies of `xcurrent` separately to the total iteration count.

The inner (serial) loop can use the normal `if fxcurrent < fmin; xmin = xcurrent; end` construct to update its best solution, and the outer (parallel) loop can just store all solutions using slicing. As a final step you select the best solution from your (small) set.